# How to prevent Terraform plan from reporting changes for GCP key rotation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have set up a Terraform configuration to rotate GCP keys for multiple service accounts. The keys are rotated daily and stored as GitLab environment variables.

```
resource "time_rotating" "gcp_sa_private_key_rotation" {
  rotation_days = var.private_key_rotation_days
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "gcp_sa_private_key" {
  service_account_id = var.gcp_service_account_id

  keepers = {
    rotation_time = time_rotating.gcp_sa_private_key_rotation.rfc3339
  }
}

resource "gitlab_group_variable" "gcp_sa_private_key" {
  group = var.gitlab_group_id
  key = var.gitlab_variable_key
  value = google_service_account_key.gcp_sa_private_key.private_key
  protected = true
  masked = true
}
```

The keys were created successfully, but I have noticed that Terraform plan reports changes for each execution, e.g:

```
module.my_list_of_accounts["my_service_account"].google_service_account_key.gcp_sa_private_key has been deleted
  - resource "google_service_account_key" "gcp_sa_private_key" {
      - id                 = "my_key_id" -> null
      - keepers            = {
          - "rotation_time" = "2023-03-10T10:04:19Z"
        } -> null
      - key_algorithm      = "KEY_ALG_RSA_2048" -> null
      - name               = "my_key_id" -> null
      - private_key        = (sensitive value)
      - private_key_type   = "TYPE_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE" -> null
      - public_key         = "my_public_key_value" -> null
      - public_key_type    = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE" -> null
      - service_account_id = "my_service_account_id_value" -> null
      - valid_after        = "2023-03-10T10:04:20Z" -> null
      - valid_before       = "9999-12-31T23:59:59Z" -> null
    }
```

I have tried running the apply command, but it says that no changes have been detected.

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration
and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
```

What can I do to prevent Terraform's plan from reporting changes? I want the keys to be rotated only when it's time to rotate.

I tried to execute `terraform refresh` before `terraform plan` which resulted in creating a second key.

Comment: Did you try [ignore_changes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have no idea how to use it in this context. 
Also, I tried to execute `terraform refresh` before `terraform plan` which resulted in creating a second key.

Comment: This is possibly a GCP provider issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for the issue - it was on my side. It turns out that the service account I used did not have the `roles/iam.serviceAccountViewer` role.